# Quartz Clock Does the magnetic field follow the magnet in the torus even if the entire torus is not encircled in wire?

Tags: electromagnetism, time

Basically, inside the clock I opened I saw a device similarly to this:

http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/imgmag/tor.gif

but with the wires only encircling a portion of the torus.  As current flows, it induces a magnetic field that I believe follows the torus, but what happens when there is no more wire, are the magnetic field lines going to just diverge? I was told that the magnetic field  would continue to follow the metal piece because magnetizing a portion of the metal, causes the rest of the material to be magnetized as well. If this is the case, then could you explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A coarse way of thinking about this is that (ferro-)magnetic materials are offering a path of lower resistance for field lines than the vacuum, therefor magnetic field lines will preferentially flow throw such magnetic materials. There is a precise physical formulation of this using H and B fields and the principle that the field will minimize the total energy of the system, but for your application it's probably enough to say that the field in a magnetic torus will have rotation symmetry, if the coil is covering the entire torus. In the case of a partial winding, the field will be somewhat stronger where the winding is and there will be a slight outflux of a few field lines at the ends of the winding, but for sufficiently high relative permeability (>100), most of the field lines will stay in the torus. In practice this does often not matter and engineers chose the flexibility of placing a partial winding on a torus over the loss of some of the magnetization.